# Test that an expression fails type checking

Tags: unit-testing, typescript

I'm writing a library in TypeScript, and I want to check that my type definitions are correct. Often, I want to check that a variable has a certain static type. I usually do it like this:

```
let expectedToBeString : string = Api.callFunction("param1", 2, []);
```

But sometimes, a type might be widened to `any` without me knowing about it, so the above expression would still compile. So I'd want to make sure it's *not* `any` by writing an expression that will intentionally fail type checking.

Sometimes I also want to check that my set of overloads works for legal types, but not for illegal ones, but the only way to make sure of that is to raise a compilation error.

How can I verify that a compilation error is being raised when it should be?

Comment: What do you mean by "a type might be widened to `any` without me knowing about it"..?

Comment: @obe Sometimes types are widened to any unexpectedly.

Comment: Can you give an example? Maybe I just don't understand what you mean by "unexpectedly"... AFAIK TypeScript doesn't change types unless it's told to...

Comment: @obe Well, I didn't say I didn't tell it to :) It's not like bugs are caused by software misbehaving and not listening to your instructions. I just didn't understand exactly what I was telling it. But I've seen it happen in situations involving type parameters where the type parameter is inferred to be `any`.

Comment: i think it might help me to see an actual example. Anyway, when I work with APIs that can return <any> I usually wrap them in my own classes that abstract away <any>, or any other ugliness...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting issue.  When [conditional types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316) are released in TypeScript v2.8, coming out supposedly sometime this month (March 2018), or available now at `typescript@next`, you will be able to do something like this:

```
type ReplaceAny<T, R> = 0 extends (1 & T) ? R : T
```

The `ReplaceAny<T, R>` type will be `T` *unless* `T` is `any`, in which case it will be `R`.  No normal type `T` should satisfy `0 extends (1 & T)`, since `1 & T` should be at least as narrow as `1`, and `0` is not a subtype of `1`.  But the `any` type in TypeScript breaks the rules: it's considered to be both a supertype of and a subtype of every other type (more or less).  Which means that `1 & any` becomes `any`, and `0 extends any` is true.  So `0 extends (1 & T)` behaves like an `any` detector.

Now we can make a convenience function like this:

```
const replaceAny = <R>() => <T>(x: T): ReplaceAny<T,R> => x as any;
```

If you call `replaceAny<{}>()`, it produces a function which will take any input and return a value of type `{}` if that input is of type `any`.

So let's examine some scenarios:

```
declare const Api: {
    callFunctionS(...args: any[]): string,
    callFunctionN(...args: any[]): number,
    callFunctionA(...args: any[]): any,
}

let expectedToBeString: string;

expectedToBeString =
    replaceAny<{}>()(Api.callFunctionS("param1", 2, []));
    // okay

expectedToBeString =
    replaceAny<{}>()(Api.callFunctionN("param1", 2, []));
    // error, number not assignable to string

expectedToBeString =
    replaceAny<{}>()(Api.callFunctionA("param1", 2, []));
    // error, {} not assignable to string
```

The first two behave as you expect, where `expectedToBeString` is happy with `callFunctionS()` but angry about `callFunctionN()`.  The new behavior is that it is also angry about `callFunctionA()`, since `replaceAny<{}>()` causes the return value to be of type `{}` instead of `any`, and `{}` is not assignable to `string`.

Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: I honestly have to say... This is absolutely brilliant.